# How to verify crowdsale contract on etherscan

Tags: contract-development, verify

I'm deployed a crowdsale contract how to verify my contract on etherscan.io

Answer (score 1):

Goto your smart contract's code tab on etherscan.io; you can see the verify link and follow step on the site.

For example: https://etherscan.io/address/0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07#code

Comment: I don't know my abi

Comment: How to find abi

Comment: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x64dc603fe143c9264045af934bdb2b8d64a26bf3

Comment: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x64dc603fe143c9264045af934bdb2b8d64a26bf3

Comment: Thats my contract how to verify this contract

Comment: paste your full smart contract code into this https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/verifyContract?a=0x64dc603fe143c9264045af934bdb2b8d64a26bf3; ABI is just an optional, you dont need to input.

Comment: But I'm always fail to verify my contract

Comment: Check your local solc version that you used to build the smart contract should be the same with your selection version in etherscan

Comment: That's same but i don't know why contract not verify

Comment: Try to select optimize with no to see what happen?

Comment: Again failed check

Comment: can you send your contract code via gist then we can try together :)

Comment: it seems that Rinkeby have problem now https://blog.infura.io/rinkeby-consensus-post-mortem-4abbcace0539

You can try with Kovan or Ropsten to see what happen.